# Dialyzer emits Type specification is a subtype of the success typing for multiple functions with same name

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I have the following two functions and I am receiving this dialyzer warning on them:

```
"Type specification 'Elixir.MyModule':calculate(arg1::'Elixir.String':t(),arg2::'Elixir.CustomType':t(),arg3::'Elixir.String':t()) -> 'ok' | 'error'; calculate(arg1::'Elixir.String':t(),arg2::'Elixir.CustomType':t(),arg3::maybe_improper_list()) -> 'ok' | 'error' is a subtype of the success typing: 'Elixir.MyModule':calculate(binary(),#{'__struct__':='Elixir.CustomType', _=>_},binary() | maybe_improper_list()) -> 'error' | 'ok'"
```

Here are the functions:

```
@spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, arg2 :: CustomType.t, arg3 :: String.t)
def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{} = arg2, arg3) when is_binary(arg1) and is_binary(arg3) do
  calculate(arg1, arg2, [arg3])
end

@spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, arg2 :: CustomType.t, arg3 :: maybe_improper_list())
def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{prop1: val, prop2: val2}, arg3) when is_binary(arg1) and is_integer(val2) and is_binary(val) and is_list(arg3) do
...
end
```

I don't understand why I am getting this warning. I thought this is the correct way to write functions with different argument types in Elixir but given Dialyzer keeps emitting warnings, I am beginning to wonder if I am writing this code incorrectly?

---

```
defmodule CustomType do
  @type t :: %CustomType{
    prop1: String.t(),
    prop2: integer(),
    prop3: String.t(),
    prop4: boolean(),
    ...
  }
end
```

---

These are the dialyzer flags I am running with:

```
dialyzer: [
  flags: ~w[underspecs overspecs race_conditions error_handling unmatched_returns]a
]
```

---

Repro Sample:

```
defmodule MyCustomType do
    @type t :: %MyCustomType{
        prop1: String.t(),
        prop2: integer(),
        prop3: String.t()
    }

    defstruct [:prop1, :prop2, :prop3]
end

defmodule MyModule do
    @spec calculate(String.t, 
                    MyCustomType.t, 
                    String.t) 
    :: :ok
    def calculate(arg1, %MyCustomType{} = arg2, arg3) when is_binary(arg1) and is_binary(arg3) do
        calculate(arg1, arg2, [arg3])
    end

    @spec calculate(String.t, 
                    MyCustomType.t, 
                    maybe_improper_list) 
    :: :ok
    def calculate(arg1, %MyCustomType{prop1: val, prop2: val2}, arg3) when is_binary(arg1) and is_list(arg3) and is_binary(val) and is_integer(val2) do
        :ok
    end
end
```

Here are the warnings I am getting:

```
      Type specification 'Elixir.MyModule':calculate
          ('Elixir.String':t(),
          'Elixir.MyCustomType':t(),
          'Elixir.String':t()) ->
             'ok';
         ('Elixir.String':t(),
          'Elixir.MyCustomType':t(),
          maybe_improper_list()) ->
             'ok' is a subtype of the success typing: 'Elixir.MyModule':calculate
          (binary(),
          #{'__struct__' := 'Elixir.MyCustomType',
            'prop1' := binary(),
            'prop2' := integer(),
            _ => _},
          binary() | maybe_improper_list()) ->
             'ok'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see any elixir typespec tutorials where they write the @spec with the variable names in the spec--instead all I find are tutorials with types only in the typespec:

```
@spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, arg2 :: CustomType.t, arg3 :: String.t)

v.

@spec calculate(String.t, CustomType.t, String.t)
```

Nevertheless, the following passed dialyzer for me:

```
defmodule CustomType do
  @type t :: %CustomType{}
  defstruct a: nil, b: nil
end

defmodule MyModule do

  @spec calculate(arg1::String.t, arg2::CustomType.t, arg3::String.t) :: number

  #def calculate(<<arg1::binary>>, %CustomType{} = arg2, <<arg3::binary>>) do
  def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{} = arg2, arg3) when is_binary(arg1) and is_binary(arg3) do
    calculate(arg1, arg2, [arg3])
  end

  @spec calculate(String.t, CustomType.t, maybe_improper_list()) :: number

  def calculate(<<arg1::binary>>, %CustomType{} = arg2, arg3) when is_list(arg3) do
    123
  end

end
```

---

```
~/elixir_programs/friends$ mix dialyzer
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: variable "arg1" is unused (if the variable is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)
  lib/friends/my_module.ex:17

warning: variable "arg2" is unused (if the variable is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)
  lib/friends/my_module.ex:17

Checking PLT...
[:compiler, :connection, :crypto, :db_connection, :decimal, :ecto, :elixir,
 :kernel, :logger, :poolboy, :postgrex, :stdlib]
PLT is up to date!
Starting Dialyzer
dialyzer args: [
  check_plt: false,
  init_plt: '/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/dialyxir_erlang-20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt',
  files_rec: ['/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/lib/friends/ebin'],
  warnings: [:unknown]
]
done in 0m1.43s
done (passed successfully)
```

I will say that I find this syntax:

```
@spec calculate(String.t, CustomType.t, String.t)
```

much easier to read.

According to [Learn You Some Erlang](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer):

> ```
> is a subtype of the success typing
> ```
>
> This warns you that in fact, your specification is way too strict for
>   what your code is expected to accept, and tells you (albeit
>   indirectly) that you should either make your type specification
>   looser, or validate your inputs and outputs better in your functions
>   to reflect the type specification.

However, I am unable to produce your dialyzer output:

```
defmodule CustomType do
  @type t :: %CustomType{}
  defstruct a: nil, b: nil
end

defmodule MyModule do

  @spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, 
                  arg2 :: CustomType.t, 
                  arg3 :: String.t) 
  :: :ok | :error

  def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{} = arg2, arg3) 
  when is_binary(arg1) and is_binary(arg3) do
    calculate(arg1, arg2, [arg3])
  end

  @spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, 
                  arg2 :: CustomType.t, 
                  arg3 :: maybe_improper_list()) 
  :: :ok | :error

  def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{} = arg2, arg3) 
  when is_binary(arg1) and is_list(arg3) do
    case arg1 do
      "hello" -> :ok
      "goodbye"  -> :error
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
$ mix dialyzer
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: variable "arg2" is unused (if the variable is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)
  lib/friends/my_module.ex:19

Checking PLT...
[:compiler, :connection, :crypto, :db_connection, :decimal, :ecto, :elixir,
 :kernel, :logger, :poolboy, :postgrex, :stdlib]
PLT is up to date!
Starting Dialyzer
dialyzer args: [
  check_plt: false,
  init_plt: '/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/dialyxir_erlang-20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt',
  files_rec: ['/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/lib/friends/ebin'],
  warnings: [:unknown]
]
done in 0m1.46s
done (passed successfully)
```

So, you need to post a minimal example that reproduces your dialyzer output.  I will note that arg3 has to be a binary in your first clause, so when you call `calculate(arg1, arg2, [arg3])` in the first clause's body, the argument `[arg3]` will never be an improper list, so you can tighten that spec up to: `list(binary)` for the second clause.

============

Here's the code I've put together:

```
defmodule CustomType do
  @type t :: %CustomType {
    prop1: String.t(),
    prop2: integer(),
    prop3: String.t(),
    prop4: boolean()
  }

  defstruct prop1: nil, prop2: nil, prop3: nil, prop4: nil
end

defmodule MyModule do
  @spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, 
                  arg2 :: CustomType.t, 
                  arg3 :: String.t) 
  :: :ok | :error

  def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{} = arg2, arg3) 
  when is_binary(arg1) and is_binary(arg3) do
    calculate(arg1, arg2, [arg3])
  end

  @spec calculate(arg1 :: String.t, 
                  arg2 :: CustomType.t, 
                  arg3 :: maybe_improper_list) 
  :: :ok | :error

  def calculate(arg1, %CustomType{prop1: val, prop2: val2}, arg3) 
  when is_binary(arg1) and is_binary(val) and is_integer(val2) and is_list(arg3) do
    case arg1 do
      "hello" -> :ok
      "goodbye"  -> :error
    end
  end

end
```

Running dialyzer:

```
~/elixir_programs/friends$ mix dialyzer 
Checking PLT... [:artificery,  
 :compiler, :connection, :crypto, :db_connection, :decimal,  :distillery,  
 :ecto, :elixir, :kernel, :logger, :poolboy, :postgrex,  :runtime_tools,  
 :stdlib] Finding suitable PLTs Looking up modules in dialyxir_erlang-  
20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt Finding applications for dialyxir_erlang-  
20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt Finding modules for dialyxir_erlang-  
20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt Checking 718 modules in dialyxir_erlang-  
20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt Adding 56 modules to dialyxir_erlang-  
20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt Starting Dialyzer dialyzer args: [   
  check_plt: false,   
init_plt: '/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/dialyxir_erlang-  
20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt', files_rec:   
['/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/lib/friends/ebin'],  
  warnings: [:unknown] ] done in 0m1.26s done (passed successfully)
```

With the following in mix.exs:

```
  def project do
    [
      app: :friends,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps(),
      dialyzer: [
            flags: ~w[underspecs 
                      overspecs 
                      race_conditions
                      error_handling 
                      unmatched_returns]a
      ]
    ]
  end
```

Here's the output:

```
~/elixir_programs/friends$ mix dialyzer
Checking PLT...
[:artificery, :compiler, :connection, :crypto, :db_connection, :decimal,  
:distillery, :ecto, :elixir, :kernel, :logger, :poolboy, :postgrex,  
:runtime_tools, :stdlib]  
PLT is up to date!  
Starting Dialyzer  
dialyzer args: [
  check_plt: false,
  init_plt: '/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/dialyxir_erlang-20.3_elixir-1.8.2_deps-dev.plt',
  files_rec: ['/Users/7stud/elixir_programs/friends/_build/dev/lib/friends/ebin'],
  warnings: [:underspecs, :overspecs, :race_conditions, :error_handling,
   :unmatched_returns, :unknown]
]
done in 0m1.38s  
done (passed successfully)
```

Comment: “I don't see any elixir typespec tutorials [...]”— http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#specifications-for-functions

Comment: Also, please, use the proper formatting when suggesting anything: types are _functions_ under the hood, so they require parentheses according to Elixir guidelines (`CustomType.t()` not `CustomType.t`.)

Comment: Is there a reason why the first calculate doesn’t have <<arg1::binary>> but the second one does?

Comment: @ParthShah, I just wanted to show you another way to make sure an arg is a binary.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, Yet, elixir-lang.org [doesn't use parens](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html)

Comment: This is legacy originated to pre-[formatter](https://elixir-lang.org/blog/2018/01/17/elixir-v1-6-0-released/) era. Since 1.6 it’s suggested to use `formatter` / `mix format` on your codebase, which appends parentheses everywhere.

Comment: @7stud I added a sample CustomType and updated the functions in the question to match exactly what I have. Can you please see if you can repro the dialyzer output?

Comment: @ParthShah, Your specs do not specify a return type, and no one can run an example that has `...` in it.  Like I said, you have to post a minimal example that will duplicate the dialyzer output.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't feel that mattered. I will update with a full sample.

Comment: @ParthShah,  *I didn't feel that mattered.* -- My example produces no dialyzer warnings, right?  I filled in the `...` myself.

Comment: I changed the function definition. Not sure if you saw this. The second calculate() does pattern matching on selected members of the struct instead of the whole struct. I don’t see that in your example.

Comment: @ParthShah, No, I didn't see that.  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195147/discussion-between-parth-shah-and-7stud).

Comment: @ParthShah, I can't duplicate your dialyzer output, but once again I had to fill in stuff that you neglected.  You need to post a full example that anyone can run without error and which produces the dialyzer warning.

Comment: @ParthShah, Or let's try it this way: run the code I posted at the bottom of my answer.  What does dialyzer say?

Comment: Can you try adding the same dialyzer flags that I have mentioned at the end of my question?

Comment: @ParthShah, See the end of my answer.

Comment: I updated my question with a code snippet that looks identical to yours, however, I am getting dialyzer warnings for mine but not for yours. I am so confused!